# Why isn't the mouseout event triggering in React-Leaflet's eventHandlers. Trying to change Marker's icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

## For some reason, mouseout does not work in EventHandlers. Using React-Leaflet.

I am trying to ensure that the marker icon increases with mouseover, and returns to its original size with mouseout.

I can't understand why mouseout doesn't work in Marker. If you write simple outputs to the console.log in mouseover and mouseout, then everything works correctly. However, when assigning new icons, mouseout is not triggered.

So the marker works correctly:

```
<Marker 
            position={position} 
            icon={icon}
            eventHandlers={
                {
                    mouseover: (e) => { console.log('mouseover') },
                    mouseout: (e) => { console.log('mouseout') }  
                }
            }
        >
</Marker>
```

If I write the following code, mouseover works , but mouseout does not work:

```
<Marker 
            position={position} 
            icon={icon}
            eventHandlers={
                {
                    mouseover: (e) => { e.target.setIcon(iconLarge) },
                    mouseout: (e) => { e.target.setIcon(iconDefault) }  
                }
            }
        >
</Marker>
```

I use divIcon.